# How to attach Kotlin sources of multiplatform dependencies to IDEA?

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea, kotlin-multiplatform

I'm used to the automatic source code attachment functionality that worked for a very long time, but now I've observed that more and more libraries (including `kotlinx` packages) don't come with sources. How can I instruct IDEA to attach them automatically? If it can't be done is there a workaround?

For example if I <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Click</kbd> on `Channel`, then IDEA opens a file called `Channel.kotlin_metadata` with this content:

```kotlin
public interface Channel<E> : kotlinx.coroutines.channels.SendChannel<E>, kotlinx.coroutines.channels.ReceiveChannel<E> {
    public companion object Factory {
        public const final val BUFFERED: kotlin.Int /* compiled code */
        internal final val CHANNEL_DEFAULT_CAPACITY: kotlin.Int /* compiled code */
        public const final val CONFLATED: kotlin.Int /* compiled code */
        public const final val DEFAULT_BUFFER_PROPERTY_NAME: kotlin.String /* compiled code */
        internal const final val OPTIONAL_CHANNEL: kotlin.Int /* compiled code */
        public const final val RENDEZVOUS: kotlin.Int /* compiled code */
        public const final val UNLIMITED: kotlin.Int /* compiled code */
    }
}
```

Comment: This may help - https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/how-to-attach-the-kotlin-library-sources/128/11

Comment: You can attach sources as usual in "Project structure | Modules | Configure Project Library" IDEA dialog. However, these libraries should have sources automatically attached by IDEA. Please try to remove .idea directory and reimport the project from Gradle.